# C: Finding JVM library file location programmatically

Tags: java, c, jvm

Is there a platform-independent way to find the location of the JVM library (libjvm.so on Linux and jvm.dll on Windows) with C?

I've tried using the [libltdl API](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libltdl-interface.html) and that does work on some (perhaps many) platforms, but it is not working on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <string.h>

static char* jvm_lib_fpath;

static int check_file(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag) {
    static const char LINUX_LIB[] = "libjvm.so";
    static const char WINDOWS_LIB[] = "jvm.dll";
    const char *libs[] = {LINUX_LIB, WINDOWS_LIB};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        const char* lib = libs[i];
        const size_t m = strlen(lib); 

        const size_t n = strlen(fpath) - m; 

        const char* test = &fpath[n]; 

        if (strcmp(test, lib) == 0) {
            const size_t fpath_len = strlen(fpath) + 1;
            jvm_lib_fpath = (char*) malloc(fpath_len * sizeof(char));
            if (jvm_lib_fpath == NULL) return -1;
            strcpy(jvm_lib_fpath, fpath);

            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static int set_jvm_lib_fpath() {
    char* java_home = getenv("JAVA_HOME");

    int result = ftw(java_home, check_file, 128);

    return result;
}

int main() {
    int result = set_jvm_lib_fpath();
    if (result == 1) {
        printf("jvm_lib_fpath: '%s'\n", jvm_lib_fpath);
    } else {
        printf("Could not find JVM library file.\n");
    }
    if (jvm_lib_fpath) {
        free(jvm_lib_fpath);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this is a really good start, keep in mind that there are platforms where Java is properly integrated into the system in such a manner that one doesn't need the JAVA_HOME to be set for correct execution of java and loading of it's libraries.  To find it there, even knowing the path of 'java' could be a beginning step, due to the `alternatives` system.   Most auto-detects use a list of "possible" locations as a last resort, if there isn't a JAVA_HOME or more obvious means.

Comment: Still, a good start, but me personally, I would add a bit of text/explanations... Code only answers often receive negative feedback, just because of that.